# If Vue transition-group shows no impact, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, css-transitions

I'm still pretty new to Vue but I'm trying to apply a transition-group wrapper to a v-for group of divs and there is no impact at all after adding the following.

Is anyone able to see something wrong here?

This is a simplified version of the template:

```
<template>
  <main>
      <div class="notes">
            <transition-group name="sort" tag="div" appear>
              <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                <SinglePost :post="post" />
              </div>
            </transition-group>
      </div>
  </main>
</template>
```

And the styles tag:

```
<style scoped>

  /* TRANSITION  */
  .sort-enter-active, .sort-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .5s;
  }

  .sort-enter {
    transform: translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .sort-move {
    transition: transform .5 ease-out;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you try with `transition: all .5s;` where CSS transition is used? I see `transform .5 ease-out;` which is invalid CSS.

Comment: No difference I'm afraid. 

It's the same thing with .sort-enter-active, .sort-leave-active that should transition only opacity. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried to apply from this doc?
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions

`.sort-move` seems not to be part of the expected CSS class. `.sort-leave-to` seems to be missing.

Comment: That did it! 


Just needed to add this to the -move class
{
  transition: transform 1s;
}